# Error while calling a smarty plugin function from tpl file

Tags: php, yii2, smarty

Created an simple smarty plugin with below code

```
/*
 * Smarty plugin
 * -------------------------------------------------------------
 * File:     function.assignmenu.php
 * Type:     function
 * Name:     assign
 * Purpose:  assign a value to a template variable
 * -------------------------------------------------------------
 */
functionality-to-smarty-w-plugins/

function smarty_function_assignmenu(Smarty_Internal_Template $smarty)
{
    //$template->assign($params['var'], $params['value']);
    $smarty->assign('test', '123');
}
```

And this function called from the template file as
{assignmenu}
{test}

While accessing the page, it will returns the following error
Argument 1 passed to smarty_function_assignmenu() must be an instance of Smarty_Internal_Template, array given, called in /var/www/myproject/runtime/Smarty/compile/cda404646b2153274a9e77f736531c5dc7e6f91c_0.file.sample.tpl.php on line 31 and defined

I am using smarty 3 with yii2. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Smarty plugin function expect an array as first parameter. So the definition should be

```
function smarty_function_assignmenu($paramArray,Smarty_Internal_Template $smarty)
{

    $smarty->assign('test', '123');
}
```

Even if there is no parameters to pass, the function definition should contain an array as first parameter.